# How Auomated testing works and what to test?

Tags: testing, automated-tests

How automated test works and how can I try one? How tools for automated testing works and what they do?

If possible please post with examples to clarify the ideas.

Any help on this topic is very welcome! Thanks.

Comment: what would you like to test?

Answer (score 0):

Automated testing means writing a script for the tasks that we test manually.
Tools include softwares where we write a few lines of code in a sequence as we wish to perform a partiular test. Then running that script to perform the tests and generate results.
Automated testing saves the hours that we manually spend in repeating a series of test cases for a particular test.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best place to start is the xUnit libraries (JUnit, PHPUnit, jsUnit, etc.).  If you're interested in testing of Web interfaces, there's something called Selenium.  They provide lots of code examples to look at.  These tools allow you to set up some input values, run some code, and then it allows you to verify the final output of that code matches your expectations (aka assertions).

In more sophisticated development teams, these automated tests are run every time new code gets submitted to the project to make sure no new bugs are introduced.  As Priyanka mentioned, they save lots of time and eliminate the possibility of human error because the tests are run automatically where they would otherwise be done manually.

I'm sorry for not being more specific.  This is a very broad topic of discussion.